# How does one replace a character at N positions in a string in a cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, regexp-replace, gs-vlookup

I have a long string of characters in a cell A1:

```
sdfhgt9|ft8yy|1gftre|78hedd
```

In cell A2 I have a set of comma-separated numbers to indicate the positions for replacing the character within the cell:

```
4,10,19,26
```

The characters at these positions have to be replaced by a "#", so the output should look like:

```
sdf#gt9|f#8yy|1gft#e|78he#d
```

I tried using the replace function with an arrayformula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(replace(A1,split(A2,","),1,"#"))
```

creates these 4 different strings in A3,A4,A5,A6:

```
sdf#gt9|ft8yy|1gftre|78hedd 
sdfhgt9|f#8yy|1gftre|78hedd  
sdfhgt9|ft8yy|1gft#e|78hedd 
sdfhgt9|ft8yy|1gftre|78he#d
```

I am now not able to join and build one string with all 4 "#" replacements.

I am looking at solving this with the regular functions in Sheets, no custom coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
=regexreplace(A1, "^(.{3}).(.{5}).(.{8}).(.{6}).", "$1#$2#$3#$4#")
```

Or, if you want to use the contents of cell A2

```
=join("",ArrayFormula(if(regexmatch(row(indirect("A1:A"&len(A1)))&"", "\b"&SUBSTITUTE(A2, ",", "|")&"\b"), "#", transpose(split(regexreplace(A1, "(.)", "$1-"), "-")))))
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked very well.

It also helped me solve a related problem: replace selected multiple instances of a text within a string in a cell with a marker ("#").

Answer (score 0):

you can build on what you have like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("|", HLOOKUP(COLUMN(A:D), {COLUMN(A:D); 
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(REPLACE(A1, SPLIT(A2, ","), 1, "#")), "|")}, 1+COLUMN(A:D))))
```

[image: 0]

or fully dynamic:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("|", HLOOKUP(
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(SPLIT(A1, "|"))))), {
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(SPLIT(A1, "|"))))); 
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(REPLACE(A1, SPLIT(A2, ","), 1, "#")), "|")}, 1+
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(SPLIT(A1, "|"))))))))
```